# How to make the container width fit the contents when using a max width and floatable elements cross-browser?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have a container div width match the contents when using a max-width with floatable elements inside.

This is working fine in Chrome, but IE and Firefox don't seem to work as I would like. I have created a fiddle to illustrate: http://jsfiddle.net/Onthrax/bb0hcLwh/

Above fiddle works perfectly in chrome, the container is matching width of the contents, but FF en IE are not.

How can I adjust the CSS to have the container match the width in all browsers?

```css
#container {
  max-width: 20%;
  background-color: grey;
  margin: auto;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  float: left;
}
#container p {
  background-color: green;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <p>Sample Text 1</p>
  <p>Sample Text 2</p>
  <p>Sample Text 3</p>
</div>
```

Note. The snippet gives different results than the fiddle for some reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. I did some basic styling with the `html, body`
2. `#container` changes:

   ```
      - display: inline-block;

      - width: -webkit-fit-content;

      - width: fit-content;

      /* Added just for demo purposes */

      - padding: 3px;
   ```

I added padding in the #container so you can see that the #container is actually there. [`fit-content`](http://thenewcode.com/975/Little-Big-Using-CSS-fit-content) makes the parent element shrinkwrap around it's content so well you can't see it without padding.

```css
html,
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font: 400 16px/1.5'Source Code Pro';
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
#container {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #2495d5;
  margin: auto;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  float: left;
  width: -webkit-fit-content;
  width: fit-content;
  /* Added just to demonstrate #container is still there */
  padding: 3px;
}
#container p {
  background-color: green;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* Added because everything was reset initially */
  margin: 1em auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <p>Sample Text 1</p>
  <p>Sample Text 2</p>
  <p>Sample Text 3</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe `word-wrap: break-word;` is compatible with older versions of firefox and IE. However, you can use `word-break:break-all;` in its stead.

```
#container {
    max-width: 20%;
    background-color: grey;
    margin: auto;
    word-break: break-all;    
    float:left;
}

#container p{
    background-color: green;
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: I do not care about old versions, this needs to work in the latest version. However your provided solution does not make the container fit the contents either.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can fix it by changing `max-width` property from `...%` to `...px`. It will work across all browsers as well:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
   <p>Sample Text 1</p>
   <p>Sample Text 2</p>
   <p>Sample Text 3</p>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#container {
    max-width: 200px;
    background-color: grey;
    margin: auto;    
    float:left;
}

#container p{
    background-color: green;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    clear:both;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 10%;
}
```

Check out the working example [**HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/zero_point/bb0hcLwh/2/)